# asp.net publish on iis 6 - masterpage fail

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-6, master-pages

I'm working at an ASP.net application.

When I debug the local Project, it works and everything is okay.
I tried to publish the project directly from Visual Studio 2010 via File System. The publish work and there are no errors. But if I call the project via browser, I get the error

> The file 'pagemaster.master' does not exist.

I have to say that this project doesn't contain the master. The master is in an other project. But I added this project to the solution and I also added a reference to the other project. And as I already said, the project works locally.

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: Try copying your master page from the project you added to the solution to the other project and referencing it from there.

Comment: I'm sure, that that will work, but a lot of projects reference to this master page, and if I have to do a change in the masterpage, i don't wanna do this change several times. Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if it's working in local because of an hidden old copy of the master page (in the solution view check *show hidden files*).

After this, if you reference a master page from another project, you need to be sure that the fiscal non-code-behind part of it is copied in the resources.

To assure that you should set the property of the master page to `Embedded Resource` and access it using a `VirtualPathProvider` mechanism to call the Resource.

It's a bad solution, but also your approach is really "unconventional" :( You should consider other way to recycle code and templates from common projects.